# How to make an javascript row link nofollow?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do I make my javascript row link a nofollow link?

```
<tr class="thumbnail-item" onclick="window.open('<%= vind.tracking %>')" >
```

Comment: It is a little bit of an obsolete question since nofollow is obsolete

Comment: @Genadinik — first I've heard of that, source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have the url go trough a redirector that is blocked in robots.txt.

If you want to link to `google.com` then you'll open `yoursite.com/blocked.php?url=google.com`, and have the url `yoursite.com/blocked.php` blocked in robots.txt. blocked.php will then redirect to the specified url parameter, but will be blocked for crawlers. F.ex:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /blocked.php
```

[Source](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z5ZTa9yeRgg)

Comment: There is no `rel` attribute for table rows, and that video is really vague and failed to describe what "building your link" actually means.

Answer (score 1):

You can't, but since search engines ignore JavaScript, that really doesn't matter.

Comment: I am a little confused I have read this article about Google Crawling Javascript links http://www.blogstorm.co.uk/javascript-links-now-passing-pagerank-anchor-text/